# MX Linux systemd Doesn't Login After Installing Nvidia Driver

Tags: systemd, nvidia, asus, mx-linux

I've installed Nvidia driver using the provided MX Linux KDE's `Nvidia driver installer`. Now cannot login to `systemd` anymore. `Sysvinit` works but with low resolution.

I did all these but the issue persists:

- The `inxi -G` shows the right Nvidia driver is installed and used.
- Tried the Test Repo driver.
- Downloaded and installed the latest compatible version from Nvidia website and installed manually.
- Removed `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` files suggested by https://mxlinux.org/wiki/hardware/nvidia-driver-install-recovery/
- Installed the older version 470 which was previously tested and worked on my Ubuntu.
- Rebooted with any step above.

I have to go with the non-free driver since my computer freezes every once in a while with `nouveau` driver.

I highly appreciate any help!

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.1.0-10-amd64 [6.1.38-2] arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.0
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-amd64 root=UUID=<filter> ro quiet splash
    resume=UUID=<filter> resume_offset=8423424
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.5 wm: kwin_x11 vt: 7 dm: SDDM Distro: MX-23_KDE_x64 Libretto July
    31 2023 base: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: GL702VSK v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: GL702VSK v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends
    v: GL702VSK.311 date: 04/19/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 29.4 Wh (100.0%) condition: 29.4/76.0 Wh (38.6%) volts: 15.2 min: 15.2
    model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery type: Li-ion serial: N/A status: not charging cycles: 104
CPU:
  Info: model: Intel Core i7-7700HQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake gen: core 7 level: v3
    note: check built: 2018 process: Intel 14nm family: 6 model-id: 0x9E (158) stepping: 9
    microcode: 0xF4
  Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 4 tpc: 2 threads: 8 smt: enabled cache: L1: 256 KiB
    desc: d-4x32 KiB; i-4x32 KiB L2: 1024 KiB desc: 4x256 KiB L3: 6 MiB desc: 1x6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2600 high: 2800 min/max: 800/3800 scaling: driver: intel_pstate
    governor: powersave cores: 1: 2800 2: 2800 3: 1200 4: 2800 5: 2800 6: 2800 7: 2800 8: 2800
    bogomips: 44798
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
  Vulnerabilities:
  Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled
  Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI
  Type: mmio_stale_data mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Type: retbleed mitigation: IBRS
  Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: IBRS, IBPB: conditional, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling,
    PBRSB-eIBRS: Not affected
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia v: 525.125.06
    non-free: 530.xx+ status: current (as of 2023-03) arch: Pascal code: GP10x process: TSMC 16nm
    built: 2016-21 pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1be1
    class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Realtek USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-4:2
    chip-ID: 0bda:57fa class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3840x1080 s-dpi: 128 s-size: 762x211mm (30.00x8.31") s-diag: 791mm (31.13")
  Monitor-1: DP-4 pos: right res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 128 size: 382x215mm (15.04x8.46")
    diag: 438mm (17.26") modes: N/A
  Monitor-2: HDMI-0 pos: primary,left res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 82
    size: 598x336mm (23.54x13.23") diag: 686mm (27.01") modes: N/A
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.125.06 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070/PCIe/SSE2
    direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
    chip-ID: 8086:a171 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10f0 class-ID: 0403
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-10-amd64 status: kernel-api tools: alsamixer,amixer
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse status: active
    2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin 4: pw-jack type: plugin
    tools: pactl,pw-cat,pw-cli,wpctl
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 8260 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel modules: wl pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24f3 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169
    v: kernel pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
    class-ID: 0200
  IF: eth0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-9:6
    chip-ID: 8087:0a2b class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 1 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.2
    sub-v: 100 hci-v: 4.2 rev: 100
  Info: acl-mtu: 1021:4 sco-mtu: 96:6 link-policy: rswitch sniff link-mode: peripheral accept
    service-classes: rendering, capturing, object transfer, audio, telephony
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 715.41 GiB used: 76.27 GiB (10.7%)
  SMART Message: Unable to run smartctl. Root privileges required.
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 PRO 512GB size: 476.94 GiB
    block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 4B6Q
    scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 type: USB vendor: Sabrent model: SABRENT size: 238.47 GiB
    block-size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B type: N/A serial: <filter> rev: 0204 scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 133.78 GiB size: 130.62 GiB (97.64%) used: 76.22 GiB (58.4%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda4 maj-min: 8:4
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 261 MiB size: 259.9 MiB (99.62%) used: 50.1 MiB (19.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 15 (default 60) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 28.42 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swap/swap
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 66.0 C pch: 59.5 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 65 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 3300
Repos:
  Packages: pm: dpkg pkgs: 2689 libs: 1515 tools: apt,apt-get,aptitude,nala,synaptic pm: rpm
    pkgs: 0 pm: flatpak pkgs: 0
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-stable-updates.list
    1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
    1: deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
    2: deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/12/prod bookworm main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mx.list
    1: deb http://la.mxrepo.com/mx/repo/ bookworm main non-free
    2: deb http://la.mxrepo.com/mx/repo/ bookworm ahs
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
Info:
  Processes: 282 Uptime: 4m wakeups: 2 Memory: 23.42 GiB used: 3.12 GiB (13.3%) Init: SysVinit
  v: 3.06 runlevel: 5 default: graphical tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0 alt: 12
  Client: shell wrapper v: 5.2.15-release inxi: 3.3.26
Boot Mode: UEFI
```